# Will be a identical title for the same url with different parameters known as duplicate title?

Tags: seo, google, url, title

As you know google will punish you when two different pages of your website have the same "title". Now I want to know, is having "questions list" title for these pages known as duplicate titles?

```
https://example.com/questions 
https://example.com/questions?p=1
https://example.com/questions?p=2
https://example.com/questions?p=3
https://example.com/questions?p=4
```

Or google just cares about different URLs and not different parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google won't usually care about URL parameters, particularly if the page stays the same and only some of the on-page content changes (such as when using AJAX to load content on a page).

Here's a prime example. Say you have a page for a sneaker, and it comes in different colors. You have a title tag for that page. When you click on different color options, the sneaker picture changes, and the URL parameter denoting color also changes. However, you're still on the same page, and the title tag should stay the same, regardless of what color the shoe is.

Then there's the matter of pagination. You definitely don't want to have multiple paginated pages in the index with the same title tag. There are a couple of ways to handle this.

Most content management systems' SEO plugins, like those for WordPress and Drupal, will allow you to noindex the paginated content with the click of a mouse. Thus, only your first blog or FAQ page will be in the index, while your individual blog posts remain indexed because they're separate pages.

These same CMS's will allow you to structure your title tag automatically in a way similar to the following:

```
<page title> <page number> | <site name>
```

Thus, even if you choose to index your paginated content (and I'd advise against that), your title tag will still update, so they won't be seen as duplicate.